# How to display gridlines in code behind

Tags: c#, grid, win-universal-app, uwp

Here is my code:

```cs
Grid gameboard = new Grid();
gameboard.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
gameboard.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top; 
gameboard.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
gameboard.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
Border border = new Border();
border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
for (int j=0;j<7;j++)
{
    gameboard.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());          
}
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    gameboard.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());                  
}
```

I am a learner, now i want to show my grid lines, can someone help me?
thanks a lot!

Comment: You create the whole Grid in code, or you just want to show gridlines via code (define them in xaml and the show via code)?

Comment: Is there a way can create a grid that has grid height=grid width, and grid width= screen width? I don't know how to create this in xaml (how do i get screen width?). So I did the whole grid in code, but whatever I use, the problem is how to show gridlines :(

Comment: Yes there are ways to bind grid's height/width and windows bounds. Everything depends on you needs. As for start, I think you should follow [Kory Gill's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35044268/2681948) post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are learning, I will help kick start your efforts with something to get you and others in a similar situation to the next step.

Start with code like the following, and tweak it, learn it, research it, and most of all have fun.

**XAML**

```
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
</Grid>
```

**CODE**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid gameboard = new Grid();
    gameboard.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    gameboard.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        var cd = new ColumnDefinition();
        cd.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        var rd = new RowDefinition();
        rd.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        gameboard.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);
        gameboard.RowDefinitions.Add(rd);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            Border border = new Border();
            border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
            border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            border.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            border.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

            var tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = string.Format($"i={i}; j={j}");
            tb.Margin = new Thickness(4);

            Grid.SetColumn(border, j);
            Grid.SetRow(border, i);
            border.Child = tb;

            gameboard.Children.Add(border);
        }
    }

    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(gameboard);
}
```

**RESULT**

[image: Grid UI with borders]

**SUMMARY**

It's a start.  It's not *perfect*, and to get the inner borders to not be thicker than the edges will take a small amount of effort, but should not be too difficult. Hint: think about how to use `border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(l, t, r, b);` where l/t/r/b are 1 or 0 depending on i/j. I might even make this an interview question; could be a fun discussion.

Comment: @yuntianliu, please mark as answer if you are satisfied, so others can see that this question has been answered sufficiently. As an aside, you do not need to write comments like "thanks" on the site per some guidelines in help, just mark as answer, upvote, or downvote, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Grid.ShowGridLines Property and add grid lines.

```
gameboard.ShowGridLines = true;
```

Comment: I have tried this. It shows "Grid do not contains ShowGridLines..."

Comment: The [`Grid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.aspx#properties) class of the UWP doesn't contain a `ShowGridLines` property!

Comment: Correct Herdo. Yuntian Now you need to assign defined border on all 49 cells. May be this post can help you. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5412ab93-b611-4a64-b351-5d71e7648996/uwpxamlgrid-show-grid-lines-border?forum=wpdevelop